# When is the topological space an absolute extensor for normal spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Problem:** Let
$$X_K = ([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup (\bigcup_{x \in K} \{x\} \times [0, x]),$$
where $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a countable set. Give the necessary and sufficient conditions for the set $K$, so that $X_K$ is an absolute extensor for normal spaces.

**My attempt at solution:** Obviously $X$ must be connected, so $K \subseteq [0, 1]$.
Next thing I noticed is that $1 \notin K$, because if the opposite were true and $X_K$ was a normal extensor, then its retract
$$([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0, 1\} \times [0, 1])$$
would also be a normal extensor, which is a contradiction by Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

My goal was then to prove that $K \subseteq [0, 1)$ must be finite. Let's assume that $K$ is infinite, then it must contain a subsequence $(a_n)_n$ that converges at a point $a \in [0, 1]$.
If $X_K$ was an absolute extensor, then it would be a retract of the space
$$Y = ([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup \{(x, y) \in [0, 1]^2\ |\ x \leq y \}.$$ From there I came to the conclusion (I think) that $K$ must have a limit at $0$.

But here I'm stuck. My gut tells me that if $K$ has a limit at $0$ then $X_K$ is an absolute extensor, but I have no idea how to prove it. Any help would be very appreciated.