# When is a space $X$ a retract of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Problem:** Let
$$X_K = ([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup (\bigcup_{x \in K} \{x\} \times [0, x]),$$
where $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a countable set. Give the necessary and sufficient conditions for the set $K$, so that $X_K$ is a retract of the space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt at solution:** In [my last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471952/when-is-the-topological-space-an-absolute-extensor-for-normal-spaces), I've asked the same question, but you had to give the conditions so that $X_K$ is an absolute extensor for normal spaces. I've since emailed my prof and apparently there was a mistake in the problem, so you only have to prove that it is a retract of the real plane. I've made some progress but I'm still stuck on this problem and would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to interpret $[0,x]$ for $x < 0$. We may understand it to be the empty set in which case we may assume w.l.o.g. $K \subset [0,\infty)$. Alternatively it could also be understood as $[x,0]$.

Since $\{0\} \times [0,0] \subset ([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1])$, we only consider the case $0 \notin K$.

Let us find necessary conditions for $X_K$ being a retract of $\mathbb R^2$.

Since retracts of connected spaces are connected, $X_K$ must be connected. Therefore we must have $K \subset  (0,1]$ (see the initial remark).

Since retracts of Hausdorff spaces are closed, $X_K$ must be closed in $\mathbb R^2$. This means $K$ closed in $(0,1]$.

Since retracts of locally path-connected spaces are locally path-connected, $X_K$ must be locally path-connected. This is impossible if the countable set $K$ has an accumulation point in $(0,1]$. Thus $K$ is either finite or infinite with $0$ as its only accumulation point.

It is impossible that $1 \in K$ since then $X_K$ would retract to a copy of $S^1$. Thus $\mathbb R^2$ would retract to a copy of $S^1$ which is not true.

Let us show that if $K \subset (0,1)$ is finite or infinite with $0$ as its only accumulation point, then $X_K$ is a retract of $\mathbb R^2$.

Let $k_1$ be the biggest element of $K$. Then $\mathbb R^2$ retracts to $([0, 1] \times \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup \Delta_K$, where $ \Delta_K$ is the solid triangle spanned by $(0,0),(0,k_1), (k_1,k_1)$. It remains to show that $(\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup \Delta_K$ retracts to $(\{0\} \times [0, 1])  \cup (\bigcup_{x \in K} \{x\} \times [0, x])$. This is obvious if $K$ is finite (see the following arguments). If $K$ is infinite, write $K = \{k_1,k_2,k_3,\ldots \}$ with a strictly sequence $(k_n)$ such that $k_n \to 0$. Each of the recangles $R_n$ spanned by $(0,k_{n+1}),(0,k_n), (k_n,k_n),(k_{n+1},k_{n+1})$ retracts to $ \{0\} \times [k_{n+1},k_n] \cup \{k_{n+1} \} \times [0,k_{n+1}] \cup  \{k_n \} \times [0,k_n] $. These retractions $\rho_n$ can be pasted to the desired retraction $\rho: (\{0\} \times [0, 1]) \cup \Delta_K \to (\{0\} \times [0, 1])  \cup (\bigcup_{x \in K} \{x\} \times [0, x])$. The only non-trivial part is the continuity of the $\rho$. This is obvious in all points with first coordinate $> 0$. The only point with first coordinate $0$ is $(0,0)$. Any neigbborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ contains all but finitely many $R_n$. Since the $\rho_n$ have the property $\rho_n(R_n) \subset R_n$, we see that $\rho$ maps a neighborhood $V$ of $(0,0)$ into $U$.